# Viewing xml in the browser: can i collapse all nodes?

Tags: xml, browser

I generate an xml representation of a large nested folder that we have, which people can then view in a browser (chrome, firefox or safari), just using the browser's default xml-viewing display.

When it opens, all the nodes are opened.  I'd like everything to be collapsed when it opens.

Is there a way to either:

a) encode the xml file in some way so that the nodes are all collapsed initially?  Some css perhaps? or an attribute of the nodes, or something else?

b) do something in the browser to make it collapse all the nodes?  (then i can leave it as is and tell people to do that to view it - it's just an internal-within-our-company view)

thanks - max

Answer (score 1):

Well, XML does not represent any style information.

The way the browser represents an XML document is completely up to it, because XML only represents data, not it's visual representation/style as say html would do.

I would create an XSL transformation with some simple HTML to present it to the end user.